# Angular 10 use a component inside an other (error : is not a known element)

Tags: angular, module, components

I am encountering a problem. I'm starting an application with Angular 11.
I'm trying to create a resister page: signup.

- I created a module "users" which will contain every module about user (signup, signin, info...)
- Inside the users module, I created a module signup which will contain every module for the register page (some information, forms...)
- Inside signup module, I created 2 components : SignupComponent (=some informations) and FormSignUpComponent (=form register).

when I lunch the app I get this error message :

```
'i-form-sign-up' is not a known element:
1. If 'i-form-sign-up' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'i-form-sign-up' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

However, FormSignUpComponent is declared inside SignupModule :/

Can you help me ?

I have this hierarchy :

[image: https://candyss.fr/img/i-1.png]

SignupModule :

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SignupComponent } from './signup.component';
import { UiModule } from '../../core/ui/ui.module';
import { FormSignUpComponent } from './form-sign-up/form-sign-up.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SignupComponent,
    FormSignUpComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UiModule
  ]
})
export class SignupModule { }
```

SignUp.component.html :

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <i-form-sign-up></i-form-sign-up>
    <section>
        ... some informations
    </section>
</div>
```

FomSignUpComponent :

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'i-form-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './form-sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-sign-up.component.css']
})
export class FormSignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: A stupid comment but anyway: terminate `ng serve` and rerun it (recompile in case you did not do so)

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't import the signup module. Also this is a weird way to work with angular. You should not have module in module.